# Javascript escaping the dot in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate email addresses in javascript, I tried this

```
/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/
```

but it matched the input "b@aaa", where the middle "a" letter should be a dot to match.
and tried not to escape the dot like this:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/
```

and it matched the input too.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Because I wanted to know why, as I use regular expressions extensively for other inputs other than emails, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need 2 backslashes:

`/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/`

Comment: Thanks, adding another backslash worked (although I don't know why :) )

Comment: Because regex is also a type of string and \ has special meaning in string, so you need 2 of them to actually create a \.

Comment: but like this, other backslashes should be doubled too, ^[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+\\@[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+" and if it worked without doubling, it worked as it doesn't need escaping (the @ sign) and the hyphen is the last item in the square brackets, right?